# How to add a DynamoDB scan result to an object list?

Tags: java, iterator, amazon-dynamodb

I am performing a scan on a DynamoDB table and I need to then add respective attributes from the returned items to a list of type `User` (`User` has a single constructor `User(String uuid)`). The code currently successfully scans the DB and returns a `List` of the scan results. However my iteration seems to return null for some reason.

```
    AmazonDynamoDBClient client = dynamoClient.getDynamoClient();
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);

    try {
        DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();

        Map<String, Condition> scanFilter = new HashMap<String, Condition>();
        Condition scanCondition = 
            new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.NOT_NULL);
        scanFilter.put("uuid", scanCondition);
        scanExpression.setScanFilter(scanFilter);

        List scanResults = mapper.scan(UserAccounts.class, scanExpression);

        for (Iterator it = scanResults.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            //User user = (User) it.next();
            allUserSummary.add(new User(scanResults.get(1).toString()));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO
    }
```

Comment: place print out in side the for loop and see if it prints your user... also make sure its being done in postconstractor and not in your getter of the allUserSummary

Comment: @Daniel I can confirm that the problem is coming from this line: `allUserSummary.add(new User(scanResults.get(1).toString()));` If I put a print statement in the iterator I get the correct number of users returned but obviously the users are empty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you start using the modern and compact list iteration by means of [The For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html), which helps to avoid many common errors when using the old iteration style:

> [...]
>
> The iterator is just clutter. Furthermore, it is an opportunity for
>   error. The iterator variable occurs three times in each loop: that is
>   two chances to get it wrong. The for-each construct gets rid of the
>   clutter and the opportunity for error. Here is how the example looks
>   with the for-each construct:
>
> ```
> void cancelAll(Collection<TimerTask> c) {
>     for (TimerTask t : c)
>         t.cancel();
> }
> ```

Applying this to your use case yields the following approximately:

```
    List<UserAccounts> scanResults = mapper.scan(UserAccounts.class, scanExpression);

    for (UserAccounts userAccounts : scanResults) {
        allUserSummary.add(new User(userAccounts.toString()));
    }
```

In case this doesn't work already, it could hint towards the actual error as well, insofar your code assumes the `toString()` of class `UserAccounts` to return the *uuid*, which may or may not be the case. The usual approach is to have a `getKey()` or `getUuidAttribute()` method and respective annotations `@DynamoDBHashKey` or `@DynamoDBAttribute`, as shown in the example for [Class DynamoDBMapper](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html), e.g.:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "UserAccounts")
 public class UserAccounts{     
     private String key; // or uuid right away

     @DynamoDBHashKey
     public String getKey() {
         return key;
     }

     public void setKey(String key) {
         this.key = key;
     }

     // ...
 }
```

This would obviously yield the following for your example:

```
    List<UserAccounts> scanResults = mapper.scan(UserAccounts.class, scanExpression);

    for (UserAccounts userAccounts : scanResults) {
        allUserSummary.add(new User(userAccounts.getKey()));
    }
```